# eclipse code for skype video call

Tags: java, android, skype

I'm looking for an example project for Eclipse demonstrating Skype video calling on Android. I've tried a number of Skype intent implementations from Stack Overflow but cannot get the projects to build or run. I am a beginner, so I need a complete implementation and project that I can import as well as instructions for doing this on Eclipse.

The following code shows my App's current state:

```
package com.example.newpro;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String contactUserName="nithya92";

        skypeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + contactUserName + 
            "?call&video=true"));

        //make call only then use  bellow given code
        //skypeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + contactUserName+ "?call"));

        skypeIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider",
            "com.skype.raider.Main"));
        skypeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        MainActivity.this.startActivity(skypeIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button skype=(Button)findViewById(R.id.skypevideocall);
    final EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

      // Skype Video call button click event code here
      skype.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
         String skypeName = edit.getText().toString();
         if(skypeName.length()< 6)
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username:Minimun 6 Character",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


         Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse("skype:"+skypeName+"?call&video=true");
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         myIntent.setData(skypeUri);
         startActivity(myIntent);
       }
      });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Add the following details in manifest file,

```
<intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Add the following details in manifest file,                   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>